# Does Solidity inline mathematical calculations that involve only constants?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, overflow, constant

Take the following code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.19 <0.9.0;

contract Foo {
    uint256 public constant SIZE = 10;

    function func(uint256 x) external pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 y = SIZE * 3;
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Since this function doesn't wrap the calculations in an [`unchecked`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/113221/24693) block, `x + y` is calculated using checked arithmetic.

But will `SIZE * 3` also be calculated like that? Or will Solidity inline this value (30 in this case) in the contract's bytecode because `SIZE` is a constant?

Comment: I would think the solidity compiler might optimize this if it is compiled with the --optimize flag with solc https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/internals/optimizer.html, https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/libevmasm/RuleList.h